# Searching for multiple numbers in multiple number field

Tags: mysql

```
   -----ID 
         1
         5
         1,6
         3
         4
         1,36
         1
```

I have these `'1,6,36'` number to search.

It should find any row that contains 1 OR 6 OR 36 (e.g. total 4 rows in the above table)

I tried

`FIND_IN_SET(ID, '1,6,36')`

```
ID IN (1,6,36)
```

None of them worked.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
FIND_IN_SET(1, ID) OR
FIND_IN_SET(6, ID) OR
FIND_IN_SET(36, ID)
```

Comment: that data "1,6,36" is being created dynamically, so it could be 1,5 OR 6,24,56 OR 4,54,23,2 etc. thats why this won't work

Comment: You can build the SQL dynamically from the search array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a sql query called IN, and you should do it as follows:

```
$id_array = array(1, 6, 36)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($id_array)";
$search = mysqli_query($sql_connection, $sql);
```

Then to display, you have to do a PHP loop like follows:

```
while($ids = mysqli_fetch_array($search)) {
    echo '<h3>'.$ids['field_from_db'].'</h3><br />';
}
```

Comment: so it seems there is no way to do that job in 1 mysql line

Comment: Not that I know of, MySql, while being amazing, is also a pain to learn how to code for and use tricks to get around.  This code is (not guaranteed, but damn close) to work even on newer versions of PHP and MySql.

Comment: Other people that have asked the same question have the same answers by my searches. It appears that you have to search the DB as an array, I have used the same code in the past to search for words from posts. It works, but it is a little bit of a pain at first.